# How can I make my score Increase Every Level?

Tags: unity

I m implementing a simple score system. everything works fine but when I leave the game and then the last score fetch using debugging but score text not updated??

ex:

Level1:100

Level2:200

Level3:300

Level4:400

every level to increase my score 100??

```
//firstscenes.cs //this is my first scene script and when I press the Play button then my game start
void Awake()
{
   PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
   print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score));

   player.Instance.scoretext.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score").ToString();
   print(player.Instance.scoretext.text);
}
```

```
playerscore.cs

public static class playerscore
{
    public static int Score = 0;
}
```

player.cs

```
private void Awake()
{
            //get the last score
            PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
            print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score));
            //get the last score text
            scoretext.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score").ToString();
            print(scoretext.text);

            //set the score when score going to one scene to another scene
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
            scoretext.text = ("" + playerscore.Score);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
   }

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
   if (col.gameObject.tag == "roadfinishline") //ex:Level1 player collide with roadfinishline then score=100, Level2 player collide with roadfinishline then score=200,Level3 player collide with roadfinishline then score=300 
   {
                playerscore.Score += 100;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);    //scoreadd=100 
                scoretext.text = ("" + playerscore.Score);
                Debug.Log("scoreadd:" + playerscore.Score);
   }
}
```

last score and last score text fetch successfully but score text not updated. see my debugging

ref:

[image]

Comment: [Cross site duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770976/how-can-i-make-my-score-increase-every-level) are [discouraged](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/264/75627).

Comment: Are your levels individual scenes or does every level take place in the same scene? If the latter, where do you store the information unique to each level?

Comment: @Philipp Level 3: the last score is:300
and I leave the game and again play the game then my last score not display last score not fetch when restarting a game

Comment: @Philipp last score text not updated but when I m debugging then score text is 200.

Comment: @jarakbans You didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

in unity all behaviours and function classes derive from **monoBehaviour** but data can be an static class.

```
public static PlayerData
{
public static int Score=0;
}
```

then in you monobehaviour:

```
     void Awake()
        {
        PlayerData.Score+=100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", PlayerData.Score);    
        scoretext.text = ("" + PlayerData.Score);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", PlayerData.Score);
        }
```

so you can work with shared data in all scenes.

Comment: score text does not update and scores not increase??

Comment: in my code i just updated score. now you can update it anywhere you want. i just update my answer @jarakbans

Comment: score text and score increase in my game but now the issue is Level 3: the last score is:300 and I leave the game and again play the game then my last score does not display last score not fetch when restarting a game

Comment: @jarakbans your static PlayerData class is on you ram. so when you close the game in editor or game... it is removed. you have to save it in hard disk and retrieve it in first scene you open the game. use PlyerPrefs.SetInt() and GetInt() to set it on hard disk and retrive from it